# Statistics Question: Fixed revenue, variable costs

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Given a distribution of costs per customer, with a fixed revenue per customer, how would I work out what the profit would be on:

- mean cost: $\$3.00$
- standard deviation cost: $\$2.00$
- revenue: $\$10$
- customers: 10,000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Are the customers a number or the total revenue in dollars?  The profit just depends upon the mean cost, not the standard deviation.  Using your numbers, you average $\$7$ profit per customer.  The standard deviation only comes in when you predict the profit next time from a batch of customers (and I bet the normal distribution is a terrible approximation)